# error unit test: underfined assert_not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have two error when i run `rake test`:

```
1)Error
test_should_require_a_following_id(RelationTest)
NoMethodError:underfined method 'assert_not' for #<RelationTest:0x3dd0058>
2)Error
test_should_require_a_follower_id(RelationTest)
NoMethodError:underfined method 'assert_not' for #<RelationTest:0x3c1d700>
```

this is my relation_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
class RelationTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @relation = Relation.new(follower_id: 9, following_id: 10)
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @relation.valid?
  end

  test "should require a follower_id" do
    @relation.follower_id = nil
    assert_not @relation.valid?
  end

  test "should require a following_id" do
    @relation.following_id = nil
    assert_not @relation.valid?
  end
end
```

my relation model

```
class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :following_id, :follower_id
  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :following, :class_name => "User"

  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :following_id, presence: true
end
```

What can i do to fix that, please help me!
I think the problem is my rail vesion(3.2.19), but `assert @relation.valid?`still work??

Comment: OMG! i use version 3.2.19. How do i change assert_not to my version or i have to update version 4.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assert_not` has been added in rails 4.0.2. You need to do this instead:

```
assert !@relation.valid?
```